# Maeve's first encounter with an awake host?

Tags: episode-identification, westworld-2016

I saw *Westworld* a couple of weeks ago, and a scene stuck in my mind.

I "remember" Maeve coming across a person (or a situation) and trying to stop a host (probably giving a command), but failing. She is surprised, and says something along the lines of "oh, you're awake".

I've downloaded the subtitles of the two seasons and searched for "awake" in them in hopes I'll find the scene, but I couldn't. Now, I'm not sure if she really said "awake". Also I've been skimming the episodes, but again, I couldn't find it yet.

I find that scene kind of important because Maeve is "awake" and aware of the hosts. She starts commanding other hosts who are not awake, and she gets accustomed to it. And in this scene, she meets another host who is awake and can't command him/her. This host might not be the first awake host she's encountered, but might be the first that she mentioned him/her being awake.

Comment: Please don’t essentially add the answer to your question. You can always suggest an edit to the answer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Can I add it (the dialogue) as an "answer" instead of updating the question? If not, I'll ask Jenayah to do so. I do not want to "anwer" my question. Jenayah did that already. I just want to keep a record of the dialogue. I don't want to visit an external site, watch a video, or scan the transcript of the episode to look for this dialogue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Season 2, Episode 7, "Les Écorchés". The line goes:

> Lawrence, is it? I'm glad you're awake.

More precisely, here's the relevant transcript, courtesy of OP:

> LAWRENCE: Give in, sweetheart. Or go down.
>
> MAEVE: *(suggesting/commanding)* It's not me you want. It's him. Go on. Turn on your master.
>
> LAWRENCE: Master. *(laughing sarcastically)* Hey, master! Who the fuck is she?
>
> WILLIAM: She's an old acquaintance, Lawrence. Seems like she underestimated you.
>
> MAEVE: Lawrence, is it? I'm glad you're awake.
>
> LAWRENCE: Drop the shootin' iron, lady.

---

I found [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/westworld/comments/8ozw06/why_couldnt_maeve_stop_dolores/) when Googling `maeve westworld can't control`, one of the comments mention no being able to control Lawrence earlier in the episode. As the main post mentioned someone getting shot, I went for `westworld maeve lawrence teddy shot` and found [this recap](https://www.esquire.com/entertainment/tv/a20979124/westworld-season-2-episode-7-recap-les-ecorches/) - then I fetched the scene.

Comment: Yep, this is it. Although I already checked this (in the subtitles), I missed the previous dialogues because I was looking for something like "oh, you're awake".

Comment: @akinuri happy to help! :)

Comment: Can you also add the dialogue from the scene? I've added (updated) it to my question, but my question got rolled back. I guess SFF has strange "no-no"s.

Comment: @akinuri done, thanks for the heads-up. Yeah, it might seem funny at first but SFF is not big on updating the question with the correct identification (or updating any question with the "correct" answer for that matter) - this is my home cocoon stack, I don't know how it's done elsewhere :)

Comment: Hah. Well, I mainly lurk at SO and I like being able to update my question. Not to add an answer, but to provide extra information for the viewer. Anyway, this rule seems very specific. Is it documented anywhere? I'd like to know if there's more like it.

Comment: @akinuri sure, here are [the guidelines for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/98028). As to adding answers into the question it's really a matter of having the question in the question and the answer in the answer... Unsure if there's a clear meta about it (I know of [this one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/) but it's about tagging when solved, less relevant), I'll ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) - don't hesitate to drop there, by the way :)